# BASH multiple nested IFs inside DO

Tags: bash, if-statement, ftp, nested

The script I am trying to write needs to do the following

Go to specific directory and find all files with the `*.mp4` extension that is newer than 30 minutes and move them into a variable.

All files within the variable needs to be uploaded to an FTP and an email notification goes out. The next if will need to look through the files and find all files with the extension of `*1280x720_3500_h32.mp4` these files will then be uploaded to a different FTP server.

Lastly the script needs to move all files to a separate location on the network for archiving.

The process then needs to run every 30 minutes. Which is why I have added a separate script that runs the 30 minute sleep process and calls the initial script. So in effect I have a Upload script and a sleep script. So two questions springs to mind:

1. I am not sure about the 2nd IF where the script is looking for all the `*1280x720_3500_h32.mp4` files - will it upload all files with this file name that is newer than 30 minutes
2. Race conditions where the script will try to upload files that have already been processed or will skip files?

Sleep script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ScripLocal='/Users/jonathan/scripts/Event_Scripts'

while true
do
echo "running Upload script: find_newerthan_mv_toFtp_v2.sh" 
cd $ScripLocal
. find_newerthan_mv_toFtp_v2.sh
echo "finished running script: ffind_newerthan_mv_toFtp_v2.sh - next run is in 30 minutes"
sleep 30m
done
```

Upload Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#File Origin
GSPORIGIN='/Volumes/HCHUB/Episode/Watchfolders/Output/Profile_01/'
#To location on the SAN where the files are being stored
DESTDIRSAN='/Volumes/HCHUB/Digitalmedia/online_encodes'

# 1st FTP Details
HOST='ftp.upload01.com'
USER='xxxx'
PASSWD='xxxx'
DESTDIR="/8619/_!/intlod/upload/"

#2nd FTP details
HOST01='ftp.upload02.com'
USER01='xxxx'
PASSWd01='xxxx'


cd $GSPORIGIN
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.mp4" -mmin -30`
do 
echo $file
if [ -f $file ] ; then
echo "Uploading to FTP 01"
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
cd $DESTDIR
mput $file
EOT
echo "$file has been copied to FTP 01" | mail -s "$file has been copied to FTP 01 in      Directory $DESTDIR"  xxxx@xxxx.com xxxx@xxxx.com xxxx@xxxx.com; 
if [[ $file == *1280x720_3500_h32.mp4 ]] ; then
echo "Uploading FTP 02 version"
ftp -n -v $HOST01 << EOT
ascii
user $USER01 $PASSWD01
prompt
mput $file
EOT
echo "$file has been copied to FTP 02" | mail -s "$file has been copied to FTP 02"   xxxx@xxxx.com; 
fi
echo "moving files to SAN $DESTDIRSAN"
mv -v $file $DESTDIRSAN
else exit 1
fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about race conditions, don't use FTP. FTP is a very, very bad protocol for data exchange - it doesn't give you proper error messages when something goes wrong, the exit code is always 0 (even when something didn't work), there is no protection against duplicate or missed uploads, etc.

Use `rsync` instead. rsync will start writing the target file under a temporary name (so the receiver won't see it until the upload is complete), it can resume an upload (important for big files), it uses checksums to make sure the upload is correct and it fails with a non-null error code if anything is wrong.

On top of that, it can use `ssh` to secure the connection so you don't have to send plain text passwords over the network (which is a very bad idea today even in an Intranet).

`rsync` has powerful filtering options (what to upload) and can it can archive any processed file so you won't upload something twice. It can even detect when a user uploads a file a second time and fail (or silently skip if the file is 100% identical).

To make sure that you don't run two uploads at the same time, use a lock:

```
mkdir .lock || { echo "Can't lock - process is already running" ; exit 1 ; }
trap "rmdir .lock" EXIT
```

You might also want to have a look at [FTAPI](http://www.ftapi.com/) which does all this and more.

Comment: Since the script will be running on Xserve mac os x cron is not really supported and I have had many bad experiences with lingo and Cronix in terms of scripts dropping off. So I am using sleep in a infinite loop since I can remote in and have terminal running to check on the script. This also explains why I keep using echo. rsync on mac 10.7.2 hmmm I rather use Bash - sorry for the paste-job but I will have a look at FTAPI

Comment: Your script has a severe bug: It doesn't parse the text output of FTP. If FTP can't upload a file for any reason, it will print a text and exit with 0 - you must write a text parser to analyze the output (which depends on the FTP server). Updating the server side can break your script without anyone noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `crontab`, not sleeping threads. `sleep` is prone to failure, and `nohup`ping is a hassle anyway.

Use `rsync` instead of looking for changes yourself, if you at all can. Also, you don't need to script `rsync` like you do with `ftp`.

Comment: Since the script will be running on Xserve mac os x cron is not really supported and I have had many bad experiences with lingo and Cronix in terms of scripts dropping off. So I am using sleep in a infinite loop since I can remote in and have terminal running to check on the script. This also explains why I keep using echo. rsync on mac 10.7.2 hmmm I rather use Bash.

Comment: I don't know anything about Xserve, and I have no clue what Cronix was supposed to be, but I can assure you than my OSX Lion laptop runs `crontab` in the identical way that Linux does. `rsync` is similarly cross-platform. I can't see how you can complain about `crontab` and `rsync` (unix staples) while sticking with `bash` (which is another port from the unix world). Sorry for assuming you want to use the best tool for the job.

Comment: I wasn't making a comment or trying to be a troll - just that in Tiger or later you are using launchd in a plist file for doing cron which is different than linux (I love linux and cron and use it all the time). Also rsynch when you are dealing a very larger number of files I have found that it can get messy. So from my experience I have found that running a shell scripts improves the process. Hence my question is related to how to solve this in bash and not about which tools are best - but again thank you.

Comment: Using bash with FTP (instead of bash+rsync) will cause you endless trouble, lost files, angry customer. Let us know what your trouble with rsync was and we can help. rsync has no problems at all with a huge amount of files and file sizes. Thousands of sites all over the Internet use it to sync terabytes of data every day.

Comment: @JRM: OS X (Tiger and later) have both launchd and cron, and you can use whichever suits you.  There is one possible problem with cron instead of sleep: if a run of the script takes more than 30 minutes, another will start an overlapping run, probably causing much confusion.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla - So issues normally (I believe) stems from the fact that the files it needs to upload comes from an Encoding System HD ProRes -> h264 in a mp4 wrapper. - so I have full admin over the XSAN environment and the encoders but I do not have that over the FTP environment since it is a CDN where the files are being hosted. So the times I have tried rsync to the CDN back-end I tend to run into permissions/caching issues. Where the file might be there but it is not accessible to the CMS which the HTML 5 player is pointing at.

Comment: Since this process only needs to run over 4 days and where the accessibility of the files from the html 5 player is all about speed I am going to get tons of calls if users can't view the files on the front-end. Sorry for the long explanation.

Comment: What is a "CDN"? As for "permissions/caching issues": Can't help you as long as you're so unspecific. Both rsync and FTP use the remote users' permissions to create the files. To be safe, create the same users/groups on both sides and use `--perms` to preserve them.

Comment: Sorry limited amount of characters. CDN = Content Delivery Network for streaming video. It is a 3rd party and the FTP is the mechanism by which the files gets moved to the streaming servers. So the times I have used rsync there tends to be problems with moving the files across (they don't show up in the directory - failed: Permission denied (13)) or in other instances the Content Management System that is cataloging the files refuse to play the files "inappropriate file type". I have already guessed that it is something on their side

Comment: but since BASH scripts without rsync always works I have not dwelled deeper into this. I don't have admin access to the origins servers - I don't have anyway of confirming the user/groups on these servers.

Answer (score 0):

Got the python variation of the script working (thank you Daniel!!).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Created in a rush, on the 31st October

# HALLOWEEN SPECIAL - QUICK AND DIRTY
import os
import shutil
from ftplib import FTP

# File Origin
ENCODE_OUTPUT='xxxxxxx'
# To location on the SAN where the files are being cached on the network
CACHE_DIR='xxxxxxxx'

#ENCODE_OUTPUT='encode/'
#CACHE_DIR='cache/'

#FTP01 FTP Details
FTP01_HOST='upload.FTP01.com'
FTP01_USER='xxxxx'
FTP01_PASSWD='xxxxxxx'
FTP01_DESTDIR="dir/dir/"

#Fingerprinting FTP details
FINGERPRINT_HOST='ftp.ftp02.com'
FINGERPRINT_USER='xxxxx'
FINGERPRINT_PASSWD='xxxxxx'
FINGERPRINT_DEST_DIR='/'

dirList = os.listdir(ENCODE_OUTPUT)
dirList.sort()

# Move the files out of the encoded located and into the cache dir
for video_file in dirList:
            print "Moving file %s to %s" % (video_file, CACHE_DIR)
        shutil.move(ENCODE_OUTPUT + video_file, CACHE_DIR)

        # Upload the file to FTP01
        print "Logging into %s FTP" % FTP01_HOST
        ftp = FTP(FTP01_HOST)
        ftp.login(FTP01_USER, FTP01_PASSWD)
        ftp.cwd(FTP01_DESTDIR)

        print "Uploading file %s to %s" % (video_file, FTP01_HOST+FTP01_DESTDIR)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + FTP01_DESTDIR+video_file, open(CACHE_DIR+video_file, "rb"), 1024)

        # Close the connection
        ftp.close

        # If the file ands in "1280x720_3500_h32.mp4" copy it to the finger printing service
            if video_file[-21:]=="1280x720_3500_h32.mp4":
                # Upload the file to the fingerprinting service
                print "File is HD. Logging into %s FTP" % FINGERPRINT_HOST
                ftp = FTP(FINGERPRINT_HOST)
                ftp.login(FINGERPRINT_USER, FINGERPRINT_PASSWD)
                ftp.cwd(FINGERPRINT_DEST_DIR)

                print "Uploading file %s to %s" % (video_file, FINGERPRINT_HOST)
                ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + FINGERPRINT_DEST_DIR+video_file, open(CACHE_DIR+video_file, "rb"), 1024)

                ftp.close
```